# Let $P$ has rational coefficients. Show that $P(X)P(-X)$ has only even degrees.

Tags: polynomials

I tried to use standard definiton of polynomial and then I tried to multiply $P(X)P(−X)$ but it was so confusing and not clear.

Comment: Could you please add your attempt? Like how exactly your attempt failed?

Comment: Alternatively, without multiplying, do you know any property the polynomial $P(X)P(-X)$ satisfies?

Comment: Do you know about even functions?

Comment: I forgot about that, it's so easy with that definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (by far) way of seeing this is **not** by multiplying the polynomials out, but by using a lemma about even and odd polynomials.

Claim: A polynomial $P(X)$ has $X$ raised to only even degrees (this is called an even polynomial) if and only if $P(x) = P(-x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.
Proof. The "only if" direction is clear, since $(-x)^n = x^n$ if $n$ is even. To prove the "if" direction, consider the polynomial $Q(x) = P(x)-P(-x)$. Since it has infinitely many roots, it must be zero polynomial (i.e. all coefficients equal to zero). Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ \cdots + a_n x^n$. Then $$0 = Q(x) = P(x)-P(-x) = (a_0-a_0) + (a_1+a_1)x + (a_2-a_2)x^2 + \cdots + (a_n -(-1)^{n}x^n) = 2\left(a_1x + a_3 x^3 + a_5x^5 + \cdots \right),$$ where the right hand has only the odd-power terms. However, since $Q$ is the zero polynomial, each of the coefficients on the right must be zero, and thus $a_1=a_3=a_5 = \cdots = 0$, and we're done!

This claim effectively trivializes your question. We're trying to prove that $Q(X) = P(X)P(-X)$ is an even polynomial. But $Q(X) = P(X)P(-X) = P(-X)P(-(-X)) = Q(-X)$ for all $X\in\mathbb{Q}$, so we're done by the above claim.

Comment: Okey, thanks. I forgot about that.